My E440 laptop keeps freezing after heavy processes
I have a Lenovo E440 laptop (aged 8 years) with Windows 10 and it's about 1 year that when I do a heavy process (or open multiple apps), the app freezes for about 10 seconds and then explorer.exe (and my taskbar and start menu) become frozen and then explorer.exe crashes and taskbar and all explorer windows run away:( Sometimes even mouse cursor becomes frozen for a while!
It happens about 10 times a day.
Probably not from software: I also re-installed a newer update of Windows 10 and the problem exists (BTW initially it becomes less frequent as the system becomes lighter)
Probably not from RAM: I tested different RAMs on different slots, and the problem still exists even when RAM is not full
Also, Probably not from CPU temperature (it happens even at 65 C), Battery, charger, WiFi, etc
How can I ensure whether it's from SSD (and therefore easily replaceable) or CPU/Motherboard or maybe other devices?

Based on your description, the issue is likely caused by SSD. After 8 years, I would clone the drive to a new drive.

No my SSD is about 2 years old lol @Ramhound

The way you'll be able to determined whether it is one component or another will be to run hardware tests on the devices you are able to, and swap out/replace items until you identify the culprit. As you note, some hardware is simpler to replace than others, and so the general rule is to start with the simple stuff, like memory or the SSD, unless there's compelling and clear data indicating it is something more complex.
